# Trying to deduplicate jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-duplication

I need a bit of help with making some jquery a bit more efficient. I have tried various methods, but what i have got below is the only way i can find that works best. Basically, i have 6 panels that toggle independently from each other... when one panel is visible, the other 5 hide no matter which panel is showing.

Here is the JQuery:

```
$("span.boxes ul li.one").click(function(){
    $("span.panel1").slideToggle();
    $("span.panel2").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel3").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel4").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel5").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel6").hide('slow');
     return false; 
});


$("span.boxes ul li.two").click(function(){
    $("span.panel2").slideToggle();
    $("span.panel3").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel4").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel5").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel6").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel1").hide('slow');
     return false; 
});

$("span.boxes ul li.three").click(function(){
    $("span.panel3").slideToggle();
    $("span.panel4").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel5").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel6").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel1").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel2").hide('slow');
     return false; 
});

$("span.boxes ul li.four").click(function(){
    $("span.panel4").slideToggle();
    $("span.panel5").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel6").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel1").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel2").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel3").hide('slow');
     return false; 
});

$("span.boxes ul li.five").click(function(){
    $("span.panel5").slideToggle();
    $("span.panel6").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel1").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel2").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel3").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel4").hide('slow');
     return false; 
});

$("span.boxes ul li.six").click(function(){
    $("span.panel6").slideToggle();
    $("span.panel1").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel2").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel3").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel4").hide('slow');
    $("span.panel5").hide('slow');
     return false; 
});
```

And here is the html:

```
<span class="boxes">

<ul>
<li class="one">Title 1</li>
<li class="two">Title 2</li>
<li class="three">Title 3</li>
<li class="four">Title 4</li>
<li class="five">Title 5</li>
<li class="six">Title 6</li>
</ul>

</span> <!-- boxes -->



<div id="panel-holder">

<span class="panel1">
<p>Title 1</p>
</span>

<span class="panel1">
<p>Title 2</p>
</span>

<span class="panel1">
<p>Title 3</p>
</span>

<span class="panel1">
<p>Title 4</p>
</span>

<span class="panel1">
<p>Title 5</p>
</span>

<span class="panel1">
<p>Title 6</p>
</span>

</div> <!-- #panel-holder -->
```

Thanks for your help ;o)

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript framework and you're not editing that, you're using it.  What you want to do is to make your *javascript* more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using index() method you can match index of eleemnt clicked to index of element you want to show. It would be much cleaner if you gave all the panels a common class instead of numbering the class

```
var $panels=$('[class^="panel"]');
$('.boxes li').click(function(){
    var index=$(this).index();
    $panels.not(':eq('+index+')').hide('slow');
    $panels.eq(index).slideToggle();

})
```

Comment: Just want to thank you for this....it works a treat! Really appreciate it....now need to learn why it works ;o)

Comment: to learn how a method works... bookmark the jQuery API  http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 0):

You should write an own function which contains the logic centrally and add a common class name to each panel (e.g. `<span class="panel1 panels">`):

```
function togglePanels(showPanel) {
  $('span.panels:visible').hide(); // hides panels which are visible
  showPanel.slideToggle(); // shows the particular panel you're providing in the parameter
}
```

An example call would look like than this and you save many code lines, even the logic you might have to change once:

```
$("span.boxes ul li.four").click(function(){
  togglePanels($("span.panel4"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Daxcode, it looks like there are various ways of doing this, i am going to explore them all and try each one. I really appreciate your help... thanks again. I dont think it will be possible, but if i can return the favour i will ;o)

Answer (score 0):

[changed your HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/g3h5Y/). block elements can't be in inline elements, that is, `<p>`'s and `<ul>`'s can't be in `<span>`'s

**HTML**

```
<ul id="links">
    <li class="link-1">Title 1</li>
    <li class="link-2">Title 2</li>
    <li class="link-3">Title 3</li>
    <li class="link-4">Title 4</li>
    <li class="link-5">Title 5</li>
    <li class="link-6">Title 6</li>
</ul>

<div id="panels">
    <div class="panel-1">
        <p>Title 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-2">
        <p>Title 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-3">
        <p>Title 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-4">
        <p>Title 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-5">
        <p>Title 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-6">
        <p>Title 6</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**JS**

as for the JS, we bind only one handler - to the parent using `.on()`. then we assign a number to each link which we will extract during click. we then find the matching panel and toggle it, while hiding all others that are not  a match.

```
$(function() {
    $('#links').on('click','li',function() {

        var itemNumber = this.className.split('-')[1];            

        $('#panels > div.panel-'+itemNumber).slideToggle();
        $('#panels > div:not(.panel-'+itemNumber+')').hide('slow');

        return false;
    });
});​
```

**CSS**

```
#links li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background:#ccc;  
    margin-bottom:50px; 

}

#panels > div{
    padding: 10px;
    background:red;  
    margin-bottom:50px;  
    display:none;
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have update my html and removed all the span's....slightly embarrassed, thanks for pointing out the miss use of them. Thanks for the jquery too, i have used charlietfl's solution, but i am going to look at yours too. As you can tell i am a bit of a beginner with jquery. Thanks again ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `index()` method: http://jsfiddle.net/C2PfW/

```
$("span.boxes ul li").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this); // each li
    var panels = $("#panel-holder span");

    panels.hide();
    panels.eq($this.index()).slideDown(200);

    return false; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks rcmdk, very overwhelmed with the response from all you helpful people. This solution looks even more efficient... i am going to learn why it works so well!! Thanks again ;o)

Comment: OK. The `index()` method gives you the zero-based index of the element in his parent element. In this case, you have the panels and tabs in the same order and quantity, so the index of a tab is the same of his corresponding panel.